# Google MAP API, limit on the MarkerClusterer

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a map with around 2000 markers.
I'm using the MarkerClusterer system to be able to join them and show only what I need.

but some how it's limited to a hundred marker
And I can't find how to troubleshoot that!!

Any help is more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause by a title in a marker that break the '(single quote) and screw all the end of the query
here was the line:
title: 'hostname"\n"chemin de l'are'

and the line should be corrected to:
title: "hostname"\n"chemin de l'are"

that will let me have a ' in the title